# Python __getattribute__ and __setattr__

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __getattr__(self, name):      # `__getattr__` will be called undefined attribute
        print "get: ", name
        return self.__dict__.get(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print "set:", name, value
        self.__dict__[name] = value

    def __getattribute__(self, name): # `__getattribute__` will be called all attributes
        print "attribute:", name
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(10)
    print '---------------'
    a.x
    print '---------------'
    a.y = 20
    print '---------------'
    a.z
```

And the result is :

```
set: x 10
attribute: __dict__
---------------
attribute: x
---------------
set: y 20
attribute: __dict__
---------------
attribute: z
get:  z
attribute: __dict__
```

When I called `a=A(10)`, why `__getattribute__` is called ? This is my thought: there is  `self.x = x` in `__init__` , and `__setattr__` catch `__init__`, `self.__dict__[name] = value` catch `__getattrbute__`. So, `__getattribute__` is called. Does my thought right ? What's wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at the second sentence of the documentation on `__getattribute__`: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrow is pointing to where `__setattr__` invokes `__getattribute__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    print "set:", name, value
    self.__dict__[name] = value
#       ^ attribute access!
```

`__getattribute__` handles all explicit attribute lookup, including `__dict__`. I believe this is the conclusion you already came to; I couldn't quite understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `self.__dict__` called `self.__getattrbute__`, is it right ?